# The datepickers' date are supposed not to be available for Selection

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

When you have pressed the submit button, I would like the jQuery UI:s datepicker's value (redmark selected in the uploaded picture) to be updated and the date (look at the picture) should not be available for selection.

Obstacle:
Today, it doesn't work after you have pressed the submit button.

1. If you have selected from "2015-11-17" and to "2015-11-18",
2. Press the submit button
3. The dates (the picture that Is selected with red color) are available and you can select it.
4. If you select a new date in datepicker of "from" and in "to" and then the dates are not available for selection (exactly in the picture).

The main question:

How should I enable to make the dates that shall not be available for selection after using the postback?

http://jsbin.com/gadiwoxate/edit?html,css,output

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you delete onclose method, code will be correct.

Revised Code :http://jsbin.com/giqigenano/edit?html,css,output